# When using /user/login as the default 403 access denied page, how can I add the tabs block to the login form?

Tags: 8, users, redirection

After removing the anonymous permission to view published content, and setting the 403 access denied page to /user/login, the tabs block is no longer shown with the user login form.

The tabs block shows up when going straight to /user/login, but not when initially hitting the page as an anonymous user. Also, when hitting the front page HOOK_menu_local_tasks_alter() is not being fired.

Default front page is /node

Comment: I don't think you mean '301 redirect page' I think you mean 403 access denied page, which means the URL being displayed is not /user/login, it's whatever the user visited. The content is the same as /user/login but the tabs depend on the route, which isn't /user/login.

Comment: You'll need to actually redirect anon users to get the results you want, so I think you need to ask that question instead. Which version of Drupal is it?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong thanks for pointing out the typo, using D8.7

Comment: This issue is also relevant to me. Ideas?